# What does this logcat error message mean?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

Hello stackoverflow Community,

I'm new to android and i wonder what this error message means:

```
11-11 16:18:41.909      110-259/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ SurfaceFlinger translucent=0 isOpaque=1 isExternalDisplayLayer=0 isExternalBlockLayer0
11-11 16:18:41.909      110-259/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ SurfaceFlinger translucent=0 isOpaque=1 isExternalDisplayLayer=0 isExternalBlockLayer0
11-11 16:18:41.925      110-259/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ SurfaceFlinger translucent=1 isOpaque=0 isExternalDisplayLayer=0 isExternalBlockLayer0
11-11 16:18:41.925      110-259/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ SurfaceFlinger translucent=1 isOpaque=0 isExternalDisplayLayer=0 isExternalBlockLayer0
11-11 16:18:41.925      110-259/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ SurfaceFlinger translucent=0 isOpaque=1 isExternalDisplayLayer=0 isExternalBlockLayer0
11-11 16:18:41.925      110-259/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ SurfaceFlinger translucent=0 isOpaque=1 isExternalDisplayLayer=0 isExternalBlockLayer0
11-11 16:18:41.940      110-259/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ SurfaceFlinger translucent=1 isOpaque=0 isExternalDisplayLayer=0 isExternalBlockLayer0
11-11 16:18:41.940      110-259/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ SurfaceFlinger translucent=1 isOpaque=0 isExternalDisplayLayer=0 isExternalBlockLayer0
```

thank you in advance!

I'm using the newest android studio version and a galaxy tab 2 to debug.

Comment: What version of Android are you using?  What device?  That doesn't appear to be a message from stock Android.  I've found references to it elsewhere on the web, e.g.: http://www.stonetrip.com/developer/forum/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=28754&start=0

Comment: does not fix my problem :/

Comment: Not all logs with Error level indicate actual errors. Sometimes developers increase the log level to make sure their logs always will be printed.

Comment: well I have an Async Http Post where I want to post an Json object, and thats the only error message i get...

Comment: SurfaceFlinger composites graphics for the display.  It has nothing to do with HTTP, and isn't running in the same process as your app.  You can ignore the message.

Comment: thank you @ fadden, may you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the question,

> SurfaceFlinger composites graphics for the display. It has nothing to do with HTTP, and isn't running in the same process as your app. You can ignore the message

-> Thank you [fadden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294248/fadden)