# Share intent in Android not sharing image to any app (after popup)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to share image by using share intent in Android. That showing list of installed apps after button click. But I select any one app it's not sharing. The opening app crashed or some app told sending this content type not support

My code:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/");
            dir.mkdirs();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(dir+"/img.jpg");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
            share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            share.setType("image/jpg"); 
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

and also I am giving permission for read and write external storage.

Log Cat:

I got this error repeatedly:

```
07-06 12:25:11.654: E/SurfaceFlinger(113): SurfaceFlinger translucent=1 isOpaque=0 isExternalDisplayLayer=0 isExternalBlockLayer0
```

Comment: @Amarbir Singh i am not using any library.before this method i am trying file provider. at that time i am updating my library

Comment: Can you post your crash logs ?

Comment: @Saurav thanx i post my log cat and waiting for your responce

Comment: Pls post your entire crash logs.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getFilesDir(), "foo.jpg"));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri.toString());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
```

http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Comment: i am tried the above code also .But the same problem

Comment: on which device you are testing??

Comment: Thanx for your quick response. I am testing by using samsung Galaxy Tab2

Comment: Check this-----> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909832/what-does-this-logcat-error-message-mean  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527726/error-android-surfaceflinger